# Add the missing badges on the voting privilege pages

Tags: feature-request, badges, voting, privileges-page

[The vote-up privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) lists badges that can be earned by voting up, but [Vox Populi](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1108/vox-populi) is missing.  It should be added.

[Critic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/7/critic) could also be added to [the vote-down privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down), unless possibly encouraging downvotes here is unwanted.

Comment: Critic would belong in the description for the 125 rep mark, as that is when you gain the downvoting privilege.